# Duvida sobre método de soma

Tags: java, array

Como fazer um método que recebe como parâmetro um vetor inteiros, calcula o somatório e retorna a soma?

Tentei fazer assim, mas não deu certo, a soma não é realizada.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] vetor = new int[10];
  int numeros;
  Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("digite os valores dos vetores");
    vetor[i] = e.nextInt();
    numeros = vetor[i];

    int soma = 0;
    int resultado = somarVetores(numeros,soma);

    System.out.println(resultado);
  }
}

static int somarVetores(int numeros, int soma) {
  soma = soma + numeros;
  return soma;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] vetor = new int[10];
  int numeros;
  Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("digite os valores dos vetores");
    vetor[i] = e.nextInt();
    numeros = vetor[i];

    int soma = 0; //sempre é zero
    int resultado = somarVetores(numeros,soma);

    System.out.println(resultado);
  }
}

public static int somarVetores(int numeros, int soma) {
  soma = soma + numeros;
  return soma;
}
```

O problema do código original (acima) além das variáveis não utilizadas é a soma  é feita sempre com zero e o número digitado pelo usuário logo não faz o esperado.

**Solução**

Você pode resolver isso de uma vez só ou seja quando o usuário  informar o número já efetue a adição em uma variação totalizadora e **depois/fora** do `for` exiba o resultado.

Se realmente precisa dividir essa tarefa, faça em duas etapas. A primeira é armazenar os valores digitados a segunda é receber esse array e fazer a somatoria.

```
public class t {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] vetor = new int[10];
        Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("digite os valores dos vetores");
            vetor[i] = e.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Resultado "+ somarVetores(vetor));
    }

    public static int somarVetores(int[] numeros) {
        int soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) soma += numeros[i];
       return soma;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] vetor = new int[10];
    int numeros;
    Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
    int soma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("digite os valores dos vetores");
        vetor[i] = e.nextInt();
        numeros = vetor[i];
    }

    soma = somarVetor(vetor);
    System.out.println(soma);
}

static int somarVetor(int[] numeros) {
    int soma = 0;
    for (int numero : numeros) {
        soma += numero;
    }
    return soma;
}
```